# Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1924

Tags: plugins, errors

I just updated to the latest WordPress Version 4.7

And now I get this error in the admin menu:

`Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1924`

The strange this is that the file has only 1689 lines of code. What error can this be?

Comment: 1. php errors are usually off topic here 2. wordpress has bugs, usually we can't help with that. and the right place to discuss them is on wordpress trac system 3. without a stack trace it is impossible to even guess what might be the issue

Comment: ... after looking at that code most likely some plugin is generating an error and this is a side effect of it

Comment: @MarkKaplun, excellent idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had these exact errors. I updated all the themes and de-activated all my plugins, then re-activated them one by one. Eventually all plugins were reactivated and the errors are gone.